# Adding a Guest Login For Product Stock Alert

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I am entirely new to Magento Development and I am attempting to add guest email signup ability to the Magento ProductAlert system. I have begun creating a module to extend the Mage_ProductAlert_AddController class and add functionality to the the stockAction function.

I have been looking at the Newsletter SubscriberController.php controller for inspiration on how to approach this issue while providing Zend_Validate, etc.

I have also created an email column within my product_alert_stock table.

I am now at a loss as to how to approach the rest of building out my module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this before, in short, you need to edit the following:

1. Add an `email` column to the `product_alert_stock` table (you've
   already done this);
2. Drop the `FK_PRODUCT_ALERT_STOCK_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` key on that same table;
3. Extend the `_prepareCollection` method of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Alerts_Stock` to load the guest entries in the grid in the backend (found under the 'Product Alerts' tab at a product), by default this method only loads customers;
4. Extend the `send` method of `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email` to send emails to guests, not only customers;
5. Extend the `_processStock` method of `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer`, to process the customers and guests that registered for a stock alert.

That's all you need to do. I'm not throwing all the code at you, maybe you can figure it out for yourself now, if not, maybe I can add all the necessary code later if you'd like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me starting points for doing this. I will certainly ask more questions as they arise and appreciate your help.

Comment: @Maikel Koek can you post more on `POINT 5`  Thank You

Comment: @Maikel Koek `Is it  necessary to drop to FK`  though with this i am am not able to update that table from my custom module as FK fails. Is there any other way . or what you suggested is safe . Plz suggest

Comment: @inrsaurabh You would need to drop the foreign key for this approach to work. It is safe in that it won't cause any immediate damage. The drawback is that if a customer is deleted it won't automatically delete any stock notifications set up for that customer, and the only way to remove the notifications at that point is manually in the database (or via other custom code).

Comment: can you post Code on POINT 5 that how to send email to guest users ?